# Setting the cursor's current line on a .NET TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

In .NET, you can easily **get** the line number of the cursor location of a `TextBox` (i.e. the "current line") by using `GetLineFromCharIndex` and `SelectionStart`:

```
var currentLine = textBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(textBox1.SelectionStart);
```

Is there a "clean/native" way to **set** the cursor in a given line of a `Textbox` (i.e. set the "current line")? Or at least a "clean/native" way to get the char index of the first character of a given line (something like `getCharIndexFromLine`, the opposite of the function I put before)?

A way to do it would involve iterating over the first `N-1` elements of the `Lines` property of the `TextBox` and summing their lengths plus the lengths of the linebreaks. Any other idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a `GetFirstCharIndexFromLine()` function that is available:

```
int myLine = 3;
int pos = textBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(myLine);
if (pos > -1) {
  textBox1.Select(pos, 0);
}
```

Comment: I didn't see that function :S Now my question seems silly. Anyway, thanks for the help! That exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

This was the best I could come up with:

```
private void SetCursorLine(TextBox textBox, int line)
{
    int seed = 0, pos = -1;
    line -= 1;

    if(line == 0) pos = 0;
    else
        for (int i = 0; i < line; i++)
        {
            pos = textBox.Text.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine, seed) + 2;
            seed = pos;
        }

    if(pos != -1) textBox.Select(pos, 0);
}
```

If you want to start counting lines at 0 remove the `line -= 1;` segment.